# Static constexpr of set

Tags: c++, c++11

```
enum class PARAM_TYPE_ {INT_};
enum class PARAM_NAME_ {NAME_};
typedef std::pair<PARAM_NAME_,PARAM_TYPE_> PARAM_;

static constexpr std::unordered_set<PARAM_> params_ {
        PARAM_(PARAM_NAME_::NAME_,PARAM_TYPE_::STRING_)
};
```

Why is it not possible to put this in my classes header file?

I tried for a long time to figure out why it is not possible to use the combination of:

> static, constexpr, non-literal type

But my overall c++ knowledge is just too limited.

Comment: It's not possible for `std::unordered_set` to be `constexpr`. The most obvious flag should be its dynamic structure.

Comment: You cannot have a `constexpr` object of `std::unordered_set<...>`, it has no `constexpr` constructor. And cannot have, at least for all practical purposes.

Comment: How can I see if a class has a `constexpr` constructor? Afterall a unordered set is just a bunch of elements, why shouldn't be possible for the compiler to put my elements together and save them as a constant bunch of data

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> A constexpr variable must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - **its type must be a literal type**
> - it must be immediately initialized
> - the full-expression of its initialization, including all implicit
>     conversions, constructors calls, etc, must be a constant expression

Now, from [literal type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType) we can conclude that a literal type might be *an an aggregate type, a type with at least one constexpr (possibly template) constructor that is not a copy or move constructor or, since C++17, a closure type*.

From [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set) we see that there are no `constexpr` constructors. Other two cases are not applicable as well, so you cannot mark `std::unordered_set` as `constexpr`.

Basically, you use `std::unordered_set` with a default allocator which implies dynamic memory allocation. Dynamic memory allocation is a *runtime* thing when `constexpr` is a totally *compile time* beast.

Comment: Seems like a missed opportunity with `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`, because constexpr versions of them could use perfect hashing and take up no extra space. See https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen for an example.